# Full text search and domain names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, stop-words, wordbreaker

I stumbled accross an issue with full text search in columns which may contains domain names on a Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

A table cell containing `example.com` is added to the full text catalog by the term `example` and `com`. The latter makes it impossible to search for a domain name, as any entry containing that tld will be found.

What do you need to do in order to prevent urls from being broken?

EDIT: The example query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE FREETEXT(test, 'example.com')
```

The Test table only contains two rows, containing `example.com`and `differenturl.com`, both are returned as a result. The Test database was created for this example.

Comment: Why you don't just use varchar for saving domains ?

Comment: These domains appear within text, e.g. "I like example.com".

Comment: Are you sure it's broken? I've confirmed this query yields results (both with and without stop word lists defined on the index): `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Contains(*, 'example.com')`

Comment: Have you tried searching for `example.com` having other entries like `url.com`? My problem is, that also the latter shows up when searching for `example.com`, as also the `url.com` entry is referred to by just `com` by the full text catalog.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior. If I search for `example.com` then I only get results with `example.com`. Same for `url.com`.

Comment: Can you post your full text query?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I just updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) instead of [FREETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx).

`SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CONTAINS(test, 'example.com')`

FREETEXT will treat `example.com` as if it is `example OR com` which explains why your FREETEXT query for example.com matches url.com. It will also match inflectional forms (examples, exampling...) and synonyms which would likely cause other problems for you.

If you still need the flexibility of FREETEXT for your other search terms you could use both functions:

`SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CONTAINS(test, 'example.com') and FREETEXT(test, 'some other text')`

Comment: Sadly, `CONTAINS` does not allow multiple terms in one query, which is an essential part of full text magic in my case.

Comment: It does but you have to use boolean syntax. `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CONTAINS(test, 'example.com AND (something OR other)')`

Comment: Unfortunately I forgot to mention in my question, that `CONTAINS` still leaves another problem (can't search for `C&A`). Your answer is being accepted, though.

Comment: `&` is a boolean operator in CONTAINS. You can work around it by putting the term in double quotes: `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CONTAINS(test, '"C&A" & example.com')`

Comment: I also extended my answer with an example of how you can still use FREETEXT for your other terms in conjunction with CONTAINS for the domain.

Answer (score -2):

This:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
[Domain1]
FROM [TESTIT].[dbo].[DomainTest] where Domain1 like '%example%com';
```

Comment: I would like to keep it a full text search.

Comment: like is not a full text search operator .